# How to set the shared URLCache in swift 3?

Tags: swift3, nsurlcache

This is the code we had in Swift 2.  What is the Swift 3 version?  I don't see a replacement for setShared.

```
let sharedCache: NSURLCache = NSURLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
NSURLCache.setSharedURLCache(sharedCache)
```

Answer (score 28):

This works in Xcode 8 Beta 4

```
    URLCache.shared = sharedCache
```

Comment: This works with final XCode 8 and should be accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

Here is an Example in Swift 3 increasing cache size to 500 MB

```
    let memoryCapacity = 500 * 1024 * 1024
    let diskCapacity = 500 * 1024 * 1024
    let cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "myDataPath")
    URLCache.shared = cache
```

Comment: what's the diff between diskCapacity and memoryCapacity?

Comment: Answering my question: memoryCapacity will get purged after app is terminated. Disk won't. Next time you launch, app will restore the cache from disk.  For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120309/when-exactly-do-things-get-removed-from-urlcaches-memory-and-disk)

Answer (score 3):

It works for Xcode 8

```
URLCache.shared = {
        URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
}()
```