# is it possible to get a new app session with KIF test?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, urlsession, kif-framework

I am trying to write a test where my next test should have a new app session so that all the activities i did in my previous test are cleared out. I am wondering if it is possible with KIF?

Comment: you mean you want flush out all previous network requests made through your URLSession? So you won't have anything stored in cache?

Comment: @Honey Yes, in a way I want to clear out any cache on my app so that it doesn't have any stored user data or activities.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because KIF is instantiated from a separated target. Also a new app session is not possible due the system not allow this.

Answer (score 0):

I did a lot of research for this answer, so it my not be accurate. Use these suggestions with care :)

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)

    let shared1 = URLSession.shared
    let shared2 = URLSession.shared
    let default1 = URLSession.init(configuration: .default)
    let default2 = URLSession.init(configuration: .default)
    print("shared1 session was \(shared1) urlCache: \(shared1.configuration.urlCache)")
    print("shared2 session was \(shared2) urlCache: \(shared2.configuration.urlCache)")
    print("default1 session was \(default1) urlCache: \(default1.configuration.urlCache)")
    print("default2 session was \(default2) urlCache: \(default2.configuration.urlCache)")
```

would print:

```
shared1 session was <__NSURLSessionLocal: 0x7f976ac0fdd0> urlCache: Optional(<NSURLCache: 0x60400000fb20>)
shared2 session was <__NSURLSessionLocal: 0x7f976ac0fdd0> urlCache: Optional(<NSURLCache: 0x60400000fb20>)
default1 session was <__NSURLSessionLocal: 0x7f976ac10b50> urlCache: Optional(<NSURLCache: 0x60400000fb20>)
default2 session was <__NSURLSessionLocal: 0x7f976ac11170> urlCache: Optional(<NSURLCache: 0x60400000fb20>)
```

As you can see, the `shared` session will use the same reference and therefor the same session/cache.

For `default` it's different. (I didn't **initialize** my shared sessions. I just set a pointer to them). Yet for the `default`, I created a new pointer!

That being said the default cache of the *default* session also uses the shared cache! Meaning if you create 2 distinct instances of default session then they won't have to download an image twice! So you still have a problem!

> For default sessions, the default value is the shared URL cache
>   object.
>
> <sub>Apple Docs: [urlCache](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1410148-urlcache)</sub>

What you can do is to create a brand new urlCache and make your changes with that.

```
let memoryCapacity = 50 * 1024 * 1024
let diskCapacity = 50 * 1024 * 1024
let cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "myDataPath")
URLCache.shared = cache
```

Do this each time you need need a new session.

The `URLCache.shared = cache` part will change the session that is used for shared and default sessions.

Some other options I can think of:

### use an [`ephemeral`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1410529-ephemeral) session and invalidate afterwards

by using an ephemeral session:

Make sure you see the link!

> An ephemeral session configuration object is similar to a default
>   session configuration object except that the corresponding session
>   object does not **store caches, credential stores, or any
>   session-related data to disk**.

```
let session = URLSession.init(configuration: .ephemeral)
session.invalidateAndCancel()
```

And at then end of your test, perhaps inside: `afterAll`, do [`session.invalidateAndCancel()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsession/1411538-invalidateandcancel), as this: "Cancels all outstanding tasks and then invalidates the session."

You can ALSO use default session and then invalidate the session but the ephemeral session may suit your needs better. Ephemeral is kinda like private browsing. (As the documentation says, you can't, invalidate a shared session, so don't try using that!)

<sub>I haven't used KIF that much, but I do remember its `beforeAll` being a bit buggy. I'm not sure if the same is true for its `afterAll`, so make sure it actually gets called</sub>

---

### use [`reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy/1407674-reloadignoringlocalcachedata)

It basically means, for this URL, don't ever use cached data!

```
let url = URL(string:"https://static.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60)
```

For most cases you would `.useProtocolCachePolicy` as your cachePolicy, but not here!

Using `useProtocolCachePolicy`, would just *conform* to whatever cachePolicy you get in the header response. If it was set to cache for 5 days, then you would cache for 5 days locally until making an actual URL request again!

If you use `.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` then it would just OVERRIDE whatever cache policy the headers specify and always request again from the server.

If I were you I would write a wrapper function for my network request and default them all to use this `.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` cachePolicy.

---

### set your cacheSize to `0`

```
 let memoryCapacity = 0
 let diskCapacity = 0
 cache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: memoryCapacity, diskCapacity: diskCapacity, diskPath: "myDataPath")
 URLCache.shared = cache!
```

AFAIK this cache size would affect your entire app! I'm not sure if you could create distinct caches in your app or different caches for each session, it kinda defeats the purpose!

This way nothing well ever get cached!

---

For more see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest.cachepolicy) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46120309/5175709)