# What does it mean for a value to be of "_type_type"?

Tags: swift

I've run into this error quite a few times now, and I'm not sure what it means. I've tried to look for a solution online, but none of them address the issue of .type specifically.

This is my current error:

```
private func setUpCache() {
    let urlCache: URLCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: MEMORY_CAPACITY, diskCapacity: DISK_CAPACITY, diskPath: "myDiskPath")
    URLCache.shared = URLCache //<-Cannot assign value of type 'URLCache.type' to type 'URLCache'
}
```

I've seen this error happen to other types as well. What does it mean for and Int to be a Int.type or a String to be string.type etc

Comment: You need to assign an instance of `URLCache`, not the class `URLCache` itself.

Comment: was this a recent change? Other examples online (like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249573/how-to-set-the-shared-urlcache-in-swift-3) seemed to suggest that this was fine. Thanks for you answer though!

Comment: Those examples are not doing what you are doing in your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URLCache` is the type (it's a class). `URLCache.shared` needs to have an instance of the class assigned to it. But you are trying to assign the class itself (which is of type `URLCache.type`).

Your bad line should be:

```
URLCache.shared = urlCache // your urlCache variable, not the URLCache type
```

Whenever you see a similar message about `SomeType.type`, it means you are trying to assign the actual type instead of an instance of the type.

```
let num: Int = Int // Cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to specified type 'Int'
```

should of course be:

```
let num: Int = 42 // Assign an actual Int value or variable of type Int
```